# Adding 3 jTextArea to Gui without the Gui editor

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextarea

I have taken the work of a student and my task is to write an Auto word compilation to it what is nearly done I facing just a problem. I have to add 3 or 4 `jTextAreas` to the gui. The problem is how he wrote the code I can only manage to add only one `jTextArea`.

This is hows it looks like with 1 `Jtextarea`:

[image]

And this is how I want it to have it:

[image]

Here is the code that mange the hole layout of the keyboard:

```
            button = new CustomJButton[button_size];
            jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

            // BorderLayout
            bl = new java.awt.BorderLayout(); 
            this.setLayout(bl);
            this.add(jTextArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            Font font1 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20);
            jTextArea.setFont(font1);
            jTextArea.setFocusable(false);



            menuButtongbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            // vergrößert die Buttons in BEIDE Richtungen // HORIZONTAL / VERTICAL
            menuButtongbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            menuButtongbc.insets = new Insets(1,1,1,1);
            menuButtongbc.weightx = 1;
            menuButtongbc.weighty = 1;

            letterButtongbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            // vergrößert die Buttons in BEIDE Richtungen // HORIZONTAL / VERTICAL
            letterButtongbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            letterButtongbc.insets = new Insets(1,1,1,1);
            letterButtongbc.weightx = 1;
            letterButtongbc.weighty = 1;

            jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());  // Layout left side
            jPanel2.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());  // Layout right side
    //******************************************************************************
    //      Button left Block / Buttonborder / Resize ButtonImage
    //******************************************************************************
            int xVar = 0; // Hilfvariable für X und Y Zuordnung
            int yVar = 0; // Hilfvariable für X und Y Zuordnung

            for ( int menuButtonArray = 0 ; menuButtonArray < 4 ; menuButtonArray++ ){
                CustomJButton a = new CustomJButton(); // a : Hilfsvariable
                button[menuButtonArray] = a;
                button[menuButtonArray].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                button[menuButtonArray].setBackground(backgroundColor);
                button[menuButtonArray].setOpaque(true); // Test für MAC
                button[menuButtonArray].setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 75));
                button[menuButtonArray].setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                button[menuButtonArray].setFocusable(false);  
                button[menuButtonArray].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 4));

                menuButtongbc.gridx = xVar; // X und Y Zuweisung der Button im GridbagLayout
                menuButtongbc.gridy = yVar; // X und Y Zuweisung der Button im GridbagLayout
                xVar++;
                if(xVar == 2){ yVar++ ; xVar = 0; }

                jPanel1.add( button[menuButtonArray] , menuButtongbc );
            }

            add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_START); //getContentPane().
    //******************************************************************************
    //                              Array      // Right side
    //******************************************************************************
            xVar = 0;
            yVar = 0;
            // ausgabe.length
            for ( int letterButtonArray = 4 ; letterButtonArray < 34 ; letterButtonArray++ ){ 
                CustomJButton a = new CustomJButton(); // a : Hilfsvariable
                button[letterButtonArray] = a; 
                button[letterButtonArray].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, Integer.parseInt(read[9])));
                button[letterButtonArray].setBackground(backgroundColor);
                button[letterButtonArray].setOpaque(true); // Test für MAC
                button[letterButtonArray].setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(20, 20));
                button[letterButtonArray].setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
                button[letterButtonArray].setBorder(new javax.swing.border.
                        SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
                button[letterButtonArray].setFocusable(false);  

                // X und Y Zuweisung der Button im GridbagLayout
                letterButtongbc.gridx = xVar; 
                letterButtongbc.gridy = yVar;
                xVar++;
                if(xVar > 14){ yVar++ ; xVar = 0; } // 17 / für Buttons in einem jPanel
                jPanel2.add( button[letterButtonArray] , letterButtongbc ); // jPanel2
            }
            add(jPanel2 , java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER ); // getContentPane().
            pack();

            // Berechnung der Position über der Taskleiste
            Dimension frameSize = this.getSize();
            // BildschirmBreite - FensterBreite / 2
            setLocation( (int)( screenSizeWidth - frameSize.width ) / 2  ,
            // BildschirmHöhe - FensterHöhe - TaskbarHöhe 
            screenSizeHeight - frameSize.height - taskbarSize );
```

Comment: Why without using gui editor.Tools are meant to make programmer tasks easy why code in 90 's when you can code fast and save time.

Comment: Instead of adding your textarea to the north, you may create a jpanel, add the textareas to it, then add this panel to the north.

Comment: Because the student bevore me wrote it without the gui editor and as i know you cant enable afterwards the editor???

Comment: @Berger thx conna test it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Horizontal Box and enter 3 textareas into horizontal box.

```
Box hBox= Box.createHorizontalBox();
hBox.add(TextArea1);
hBox.add(TextArea2);
hBox.add(TextArea3);
```

Comment: this works great but have one question to this. How do i can seperate them? I have 3 now but they look like just one unless i chage the color of one

Comment: Please check with hBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10)); or only Box.createHorizontalStrut(10); between 2 components/TextArea. I think it will be worked.